# every second update data firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase

I'm pulling data from Firebase. For example,I'm doing on-off section, on-off as the clock in the database is updated. But when I get in and out of the app, that data is updated. I want this data updated without leaving the app. For example, I want the data in `time_textview` updated continuously. So I want to pull the data from the Firebase every second with the `timer`. I want the data in `time_textview` updated. How can I do this?

**Main Class**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, OnItemSelectedListener, View.OnTouchListener, RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener{
    ProductsAdapter adapter;
    List<Product> productList;
    dbProducts.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
       @Override
       public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           productList = new ArrayList<>();
           if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
               for (DataSnapshot productSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                   Product p = productSnapshot.getValue(Product.class);
                   productList.add(p);
               }

               adapter = new ProductsAdapter(MainActivity.this, productList);
                                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

           }
       }

       @Override
       public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

       }


  });
  }
```

**Main Adapter:**

```
 public class ProductsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductsAdapter.ProductViewHolder> {
        List<Product> productList;

            public void onBindViewHolder(final ProductViewHolder holder, final int position) {
                Product product = productList.get(position);
                holder.textViewTime.setText(product.gettime());
    }

        class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            TextView textViewTime, textTitle, textviewPlaces;
                textViewTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.time_textView);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ValueEventListener` instead of Using `SingleValueEventListener` Like

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, OnItemSelectedListener, View.OnTouchListener, RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener{
ProductsAdapter adapter;
List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();
adapter = new ProductsAdapter(MainActivity.this, productList);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


dbProducts.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
   @Override
   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
       productList.clear();
       if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
           for (DataSnapshot productSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
               Product p = productSnapshot.getValue(Product.class);
               productList.add(p);
           }

    // here I will recommend just to notify adapter, and initialize it once outside the listener
           adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

       }
   }

   @Override
   public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

   }


 });
}
```

Now each time data get changed in the DB this listener will automatically get called and you will get the latest data. Then you can just clear the older list, insert new Data in it, and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: But from my experiences, I will recommend, try to use this continuous listener carefully, It increases Firebase billing, due to data caching.